# MKMapView initWithFrame not releasing memory with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, mkmapview, automatic-ref-counting

I've been using instruments to find allocations that aren't being released properly.  I have MKMapViewDelegate that adds a map via a instance method after it has been instantiated.  I can see in the call tree that this method keeps retaining about 300KB of memory, after the ViewDelegate is released.  I commented out the meat of the code and it stills maintains the memory with just this line:

```
self.map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 210, 300, 125)];
```

I look in the object list and the MKMapView itself isn't living, but as I keep creating new ViewDelegates, that memory keeps adding up.  Here is how map is defined:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)        MKMapView *map;
```

The map's delegate is set to nil, as well as the reference on the ViewDelegate's dealloc

```
self.map.delegate = nil;
self.map = nil;
```

Comment: How about using release instead of nil. Can you check that at your end?

Comment: @S.P. they are using ARC, there is no release.

Comment: @S.P. no one else refers to that property, right? Nothing else potentially holding a reference?

Comment: I mistook from this ViewDelegate's dealloc that has been put up there

Comment: Chris, nothing else is done to the map and nothing references the property.  As far as I know, the map object is getting released properly too as I can see it get created and die in the object view of the instruments.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the delegate to nil, there are no longer any pointers, and iOS will release it when it wants to.  iOS may not release the memory immediately after setting it to nil.

Remember, that you are removing the *pointer* by setting it to nil, but the object still remains on the heap, basically doing nothing, until something else gets allocated there.

(I'm assuming you also removed the MKMapView from its superview using `[self.map removeFromSuperView]`).

Comment: Doesn't the instruments recognize what memory is actually live and being used?  I understand that in the memory objects exist until overwritten but isn't the point of instruments is that it shows what is still referenced by the application and therefore that memory can't be reallocated?

I do have code that has removeFromSuperView, but that's commented out, along with it being added as a subview.